# Update entity via JpaRepository

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to update entity matched to **tvShowApiId** property in my database. I have entity like this:

```
@Data
@Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
@Builder
@Entity
@Table(name = "tv_shows")
public class TvShowLocal implements TvShowEntity<SeasonLocal, EpisodeLocal> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "tv_show_id")
    private Integer id;

    private String tvShowApiId;

    @Lob
    @Column(length = 100000)
    private String summary;

    private Integer updated;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @ElementCollection(targetClass = SeasonLocal.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "tv_show_id")
    @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)
    private List<SeasonLocal> seasons;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @ElementCollection(targetClass = EpisodeLocal.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "tv_show_id")
    @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)
    private List<EpisodeLocal> episodes;

}
```

I wrote @Query in my JpaRepository:

```
public interface TvShowRepository extends JpaRepository<TvShowLocal, Integer> {

    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query("UPDATE TvShowLocal tv SET tv = :tvShow WHERE tv.tvShowApiId = :id")
    void update(@Param("tvShow")TvShowLocal tvShowLocal, @Param("id") String tvShowApiId);

}
```

But when I'm trying to call update method in database provider class I'm getting exception:

> org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved
>   transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing:
>   pl.hypeapp.core.entity.database.TvShowLocal; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved
>   transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing:
>   pl.hypeapp.core.entity.database.TvShowLocal

What is the problem? How I can do operation like this in proper way?

Comment: This query doesn't make much sense. An update is used to update one or several attributes of an entity. Not to replace an entity by another one. I *think* you're looking for `repository.save(tvShowLocal)`. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @JBNizet For some reason repository.save(tvShowLocal) adding new record instead updating. I'm trying to update whole record in my database.

Comment: That's most probably because the TvShowLocal you're saving doesn't have any ID. So it's considered new, and is thus inserted.

Answer (score 0):

The error says that the object you are trying to save is not yet inserted to the database.
You could do the following in order:
1. Insert TvShowLocal.
2. Perform the update.

Comment: Alex, object was inserted to database before update.

Comment: How about SeasonLocal and EpisodeLocal, they may not be associated with TvShowLocal. When an transient exception occurred, either one of the objects are not saved.

Answer (score 0):

first you must read it from database(for filling ID variable), and then you can update the object.
if id exist in pojo, save function will update it and if id does not have value, the function will save it.

for Update an existing object

```
TvShowLocal tvShowLocal = TvShowRepository.getOne(id); 

TvShowRepository.save(tvShowLocal); // tvShowLocal will be update
```

for Saving new Object

```
TvShowLocal tvShowLocal2=new  TvShowLocal(); //New Object
TvShowRepository.save(tvShowLocal2);   //tvShowLocal2 will be save as new object
```